# Is IETF RFC numbers are permanent for particular topic?

Tags: rfc, ietf

I want to put IETF RFC document reference in my presentation. Is that RFC document number is permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are, they do not change. New numbers are allocate for new RFCs.

Comment: Thank you so much.